# d3 keeping text from extending outside of SVG

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg, text

I have line chart generated through D3, and the text appears to the right of the pointer on hover. The problem is the text that appears on the far right is cut off by the edge of the SVG. I know a simple `overflow:visible` would allow it to appear outside, but I want it to stay inside the SVG. Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this technique:

[image]

- If cursor is on A zone: align your text or tooltip to the right
- If cursor is on B zone: align your text or tooltip to the left

Use `(svg_width / 2)` to get the middle

```
text.style ("text-anchor", function () {
     var position = d3.mouse();  // position[0] <= x    position[1]  <= y
     if (position[0] < (svg_width/2) ) {
            // you are on A zone
            return "start";
     } else {
            // you are on B zone
            return "end";
     }
})
```